# Run two concurrent task groups asynchronously with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7, aiohttp

I am trying to write a program using `asyncio` and was oriented towards this [blog](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) post. What I am trying to do is fetch some JSON data concurrently. For one input data frame. however, I would like to process the requested data further as soon as it becomes available.

So basically there are two groups of tasks:

- process data in df1 concurrently and do some calc once JSON returned
- process data in df2 concurrently

They are more or less independent of each other, but I want to run the group of tasks concurrently as well. Once both task groups are finished I want to further process them.

My question is if my implementation is properly designed in terms of `asyncio` patterns, where I just used two gather statements? Or whether this is the wrong concept? Here is a scatch:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch_json(url: str, session: ClientSession, data: json.dumps) -> Dict:
    resp = await session.get(url=url, headers={"content-type": "application/json"}, data=data)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    logger.info("Got response [%s] for URL: %s", resp.status, url)
    json = await resp.json()
    return json

async def some_calc(url: str, session: ClientSession, data: json.dumps):
    res = await fetch_json(url=url, session=session, data=data)
    return [float(x) for x in res]

async def process_data(df: Dict, url: str, session: ClientSession):
    async with session:
        tasks = []
        for data in df:
            try:
                if df1:
                    task = some_calc(url=url, session=session, data=data)
                else:
                    task = fetch_json(url=url, session=session, data=data)

            except Exception as e:
                # ...
            tasks.append(
                task
            )
        res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return res

async def bulk_execute(df1, df2):
    url = "http://some.url/"

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        res = await asyncio.gather(process_data(df1, url, session), process_data(df2, url, session))

    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = asyncio.run(bulk_execute(df1, df2))
```

Comment: `if df1` seems incorrect because `df1` is not defined in `process_data`. Also, `try/.../except` won't achieve the desired effect because the invocation of `some_calc` and `fetch_json` only create coroutine objects, they don't run the actual code. You probably need to place the try/except in an intermediate `async def`, around `if df1: await some_calc(...) else: await fetch_json(...)` (note the awaits). Then *that* coroutine is your "task".

Comment: I know that df1 is not defined, its supposed to be some pseudo code. The try except is only handling aiohttp as done [here](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#a-full-program-asynchronous-requests). Wo why would I need additional `async def` with `await`?

Comment: As noted in the previous comment, your `try` is only around the code that creates coroutine objects, and that will never raise. The actual raising will happen when you `await` them, which you do later, outside the try/except block. The linked program doesn't have this problem because it actually **awaits** inside `try`.

Comment: You are abolutely right! My question was more aiming towards the design itself, whether gathering tasks twice is valid in terms of best practices for async programming?

Comment: I understand that, but it's hard to reason about an obviously incorrect example. As for `gather`, it's just a utility function that helps you wait until several awaitables have all finished. It doesn't introduce additional overhead to the underlying tasks, so there's no problem with calling it on different abstraction levels.